# Compare dates and times in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

How to use comparative operators on date and time
What is the problem in the example below?

in models.py

```
start_sale=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2018,5,3))
```

in views:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

in template:

```
{% if course.start_sale|date < time.date and course.start_sale|time < time.time %}                           
   
    {% else %}
   
   {% endif %}
```

this code dont show error but dont work
dont compare datetime

Comment: Welcome to StackOver, what do you mean they don't work to compare  the datetimes?

Comment: This almost looks to me that you could put that logic back into the model as a (convinience) function and then can be called in the template as your condition in the if statement. ... worst case, if its just a single item, do it in the view and then pass your boolean result through to the template......

Comment: it did not work in view too